# Angular (click) switch between two functions

Tags: angular, function, variables, events, click

I have three different buttons: A, B, and C. A and B are pretty much the same but with different classes and they have `(click)="function"`; C toggles a boolean and switches it. If the boolean is true, A and B's function have to be `function1(withParam)`, but if it's false it has to be `function2()`.

This is the html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let withParam of data[0]">

  <ng-container *ngIf="withParam.hecha == true; else todo">
    <button (click)="funcion" class="done"></button> //A
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #todo>
    <button (click)="funcion" class="todo"></button> //B
  </ng-template>

</ng-container>

<button (click)="activaEdicion()"></button> //C
```

And this is the ts:

```
funcion : string = "function1(withParam)"; //default value

activaEdicion(){
    this.booleanVar = !this.booleanVar;

    if(this.booleanVar){
      this.funcion = "function2()";
    }else{
      this.funcion = "function1(withParam)";
    }
  }
```

But it won't work. There is another similar question but the answer was to use this `<button (click)="this[funcion]()"></button>`, but it won't work for me. It looks like (click) needs the actual function, that's why it's not working, but I don't know what to do then. I also can't use the function in the ts file because "withParam" is related to the HTML so I need to pass with Param as a param to function1 with its corresponding values, and therefore I can't do it in the ts.

Any clues? Thanks.

**ANSWER UPDATE:**

Thanks, everyone! I tried *@JackyShows* answer and it works just fine!
I'm sure the *@Panagiotis Bougioukos* answer will also work too, but the other one was quite simple and cleaner so I took that one. For anyone who has the same problem it was a simple JavaScript if-else (I'm guessing? I had no idea I could do it that way) like this:

> `<button (click)="booleanVar ? function2() : function1(withParam)" class="todo"></button>`

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you instead use an if on your click? I mean something like this:

```
<ng-template #todo>
<button (click)="booleanVar ? function2() : function1(withParam)" class="todo"></button>
```